# A link on my websites homepage doesn't work properly

Tags: html, url, button

I've got a problem where an anchor link on homepage isn't working properly. The link works if opened in another window. The link itself works fine, also I can see link when hovering with mouse over it.

The URL for my website is https://kuddexperten.se/
The button URL is https://kuddexperten.se/collections/kuddlandet

I've tried validate the code in JSON formatter etc, but since i got no experience of coding its kind of hard to identify the problem as i get alot of errors and warnings.
I've tried using diffrent browsers and turning off adblockers etc. It doesnt work either on desktop or mobilephone.

I'd be happy if anyone had a clue of why the button doesnt work as it should.

Picture of the button:
[image: Picture of the button]

Comment: Can you include your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the necessary code to reproduce the issue. [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) (Spoiler: no)

Comment: That's not a button.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in Chrome's `Elements / Event Listeners` subtab, there's a JavaScript event listener on it in theme.js:

```
$('.btn-link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // <------------------------- here's your saddle bur
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.card').toggleClass('open');
});
```

You probably shouldn't be using classes intended for a button element on an anchor.

Comment: You're welcome, but please take the [tour]. Thanks comments are discouraged.